# Как запретить пользователю переход по url-адресу, написанному от руки в поисковой строке браузера?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, html5, asp.net-core

Например, пользователь не авторизован и сейчас находится на Главной Странице, при этом я не хочу, чтобы пользователь, если не авторизован, то мог переходить по url-ссылкам, написанным от руки в браузере. То есть, вот, например, главная страница:
[image]
тут пользователь не авторизован, находится на Главной странице не может с помощью панели переключиться на страницу Пользователи, но он легко может переключиться на страницу Пользователи с помощью поисковой строки(у меня с техническим языком плохо, поэтому могу говорить неправильные слова) в браузере:
[image]
Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь писал /added-users и нажимал Enter, то он переходил не на (адрес главной страницы)//added-users, а на Главную страницу, то есть на https://localhost:44317/ ?

Comment: У вас движок asp .net core, при чем тут js, html и все остальное?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, потому что я хочу сделать этот механизм, используя js, html and css(вдруг есть спец. стиль для этого?).

Comment: А что вы собрались на js делать? JS это клиент, он не знает нечего про авторизацию, что бы он это узнал, он должен спросить у сервера, авторизирован пользователь или нет, тогда уже он что-то может сделать, но зачем, если это может сразу сделать сам сервер без лишних запросов к нему? Вот у вас есть телефон, красивый, сенсорный, вам надо позвонить другу, думаете это на стороне телефона идет все? Ошибаетесь, телефон это клиент, который отправляет данные на сервер, а тот уже решает куда и как произвести звонок. Также и тут, сервер решает куда и как перенаправить клиента если страница не для него.

Answer (score 0):

Пускай заходит, нарисуйте ему на сервере логин диалог на этой странице, или вежливое объявление, мол "для администрации музея", вместо контента.